# How to customize the namespace of a soap response?

Tags: xml, web-services, weblogic, soapui, xml-namespaces

is it possible to customize the namespace of the soap response from a weblogic webservice?
I found that the namespace is radomized and non-predictable. it could be **ns0, ns1, ns2** and changing all the time. Thanks for advise.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns0:webserviceResponse xmlns:ns0="http://somewebservice.com/">
         <return>abcde</return>
      </ns0:webserviceResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not care of that. Actually parsers care of what is in double quotes.

This `"http://somewebservice.com/"` has to be always the same for given schema. So when you parse it, you should associate that namespace with a given prefix.